# Best practice for android layout

Tags: android

[Layout that I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq685.png)

Hi I am quite new to android(about 2 week) and read about layouts and attributes

but implementing it in best way that is known to skilled programmer is confusing and can't get it on my own.

I made layout but I don't think it's good implementation of view.

on Image i attached, I used multiple LinearLayout in depth

It looks like this. Used LinearLayout with layout_weight

[Layout I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OiJt.png)

is it better to use `<relativeLayout>` or `<TableView>` ?

I want to efficiently implement these things.

is it safe to use "XX dp" to ensure same look among different screens?

Extra Question 1)
   Issues I faced when implementing.
  When multiple "match_parent", for example

if I have something like

`<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal"> 
    <TextView width="match_parent">
    <TextView width="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>`

It behaves like framelayout so only one textView is displayed.

What I want is have static table like view that has three fixed container in ratio 1:3:1

```
   1      3       1
 |_ _ |_ _ _ _ |_ _ |
```

How can this be done? How do I have to use "layout_weight" with
"layout_width" property? Do I have to use "wrap_content"? and why?
Can it be done with TableView??

Thank you in advance

Comment: As of right now, I strongly advise against using those nested linear layouts. I believe Android had a talk or an article where they stated you want a layout as flat as possible. In your case, relativelayout is the way to go. Read: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Comment: You also have many questions in one, please also try to ask only one thing. It helps keeps things concise. Good luck

Comment: As it has already been said, you should try to never use nested linear layouts,  it is extremely bad for performance, especially nesting it 4 times as in your case. As for the last part of the question, use a horizontal linear layout or a table view  as the parent, and set the width for each of the children to 0dp. Then set the weights to 1, 3, and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example to use a weight, when use a weight your width must be 0dp:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    </LinearLayout>
```